# Need to insert row into Google spreadhseet at specific location

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using python to  update a google spreadsheet. The google python library for spreadsheets allows you to insert a row to a spreasheet using the InsertRow api.

Here is an example:

```
gd_client.InsertRow(myDict, spreadSheetKey, workSheetKey)
```

myDictionary is the dictionary you are inserting, spreadsheetKey is the key for your spreadsheet and worksheetKey is the key for your worksheet.
However, I'd like to insert into a specific row in the middle of my spreadsheet. This API only inserts at the end.

Anyone know, if there is any way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

An easy way is to have **two** sheets in the same spreadsheet. One is the raw data as it is inserted from the outside, and the second is the calculated one (sorting, functions...) that is based on that raw data.

For example if you want the data to be sorted by the second column, you can put in the second sheet:

```
=EXPAND(SORT(Sheet1!A:D,2,1))
```

This separation is also good as if you want to update the data from the outside. It will conflict with operations that you might have on your data, as adding calculated columns to the data rows.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not quite what I was looking for. It would be a lot or work to figure out the layout of my spredsheet; I have no functions to do so.  I am thinking I might have to sort everything myself in memory, create a new worksheet and then add everything again.  I am hoping I won't have to do that.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an example of the second sheet that is basically sorting the data of the raw 'Sheet1'

Answer (score 1):

How to *** insert a row *** into the middle of a google spreadsheet via the API/OAuth ..... the hard way. (I assume there is no easy way, because there is a feature request to add this to the API).

```
          Pattern cellRefPattern = Pattern.compile("R(\\[?)([-0-9]+)\\]?C(\\[?)([-0-9]*)\\]?");
              worksheet.setRowCount(worksheet.getRowCount()+1);
              worksheet.update();
              CellFeed batchRequest = new CellFeed();
              for (AppCell cellAddr : cellAddresses.values()) {

                  // create a copy of the cell to replace
                  CellEntry batchEntry = new CellEntry(cellAddr.row, cellAddr.col, cellAddr.reference);

                  String updateReference = cellAddr.inputValue; 

                  if(updateReference.startsWith("=")) {
                      String removeReferenceBug = updateReference.replace( (CharSequence) "C:R", (CharSequence) "C[0]:R");
                      Matcher referenceMatcher = cellRefPattern.matcher(removeReferenceBug);
                      StringBuffer restultBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                      while (referenceMatcher.find()) {
                          try {
                              if(referenceMatcher.group(1).equals("[")) {
                                  int rowOffset = Integer.parseInt(referenceMatcher.group(2));
                                  int topRowOfSpan;
                                  int bottomRowOfSpan;                                
                                  int incSize = 1;
                                  if(rowOffset > 0) {
                                      topRowOfSpan = cellAddr.row;
                                      bottomRowOfSpan = cellAddr.row + rowOffset;
                                  } else {
                                      topRowOfSpan = cellAddr.row + rowOffset;
                                      bottomRowOfSpan = cellAddr.row ;      
                                      incSize = -1;
                                  }                               
                                  //System.out.println("move down: reference:"+cellAddr.reference+" topRowOfSpan:"+topRowOfSpan+
                                    //    " insertLocationRow:"+insertLocationRow+" bottomRowOfSpan:"+bottomRowOfSpan);
                                  if(topRowOfSpan <= insertLocationRow && bottomRowOfSpan > insertLocationRow) rowOffset += incSize;
                                  if(referenceMatcher.group(3).equals("[")) {
                                      referenceMatcher.appendReplacement(restultBuffer, "R["+rowOffset+"]C["+referenceMatcher.group(4)+"]");                                      

                                  } else {
                                      int colOffset = 0;                                          
                                      String col = referenceMatcher.group(4);                                         
                                      if(col != null && "".equals(col) == false) {
                                          colOffset = Integer.parseInt(col) - cellAddr.col;
                                      }                                       
                                      referenceMatcher.appendReplacement(restultBuffer, "R["+rowOffset+"]C["+colOffset+"]");                                                                              
                                  }                                   
                              } else {
                                  int absoluteRow = Integer.parseInt(referenceMatcher.group(2));
                                  if(absoluteRow >= insertLocationRow ) absoluteRow ++;
                                  if(referenceMatcher.group(3).equals("[")) {
                                      referenceMatcher.appendReplacement(restultBuffer, "R"+absoluteRow+"C["+referenceMatcher.group(4)+"]");                                                                                                              
                                  } else {
                                      referenceMatcher.appendReplacement(restultBuffer, "R"+absoluteRow+"C"+referenceMatcher.group(4));                                                                                                                                                   
                                  }

                              }
                          } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {}
                      }
                      referenceMatcher.appendTail(restultBuffer);
                      updateReference = restultBuffer.toString();                                                                         

                  }


                  batchEntry.setId(String.format("%s/%s", worksheet.getCellFeedUrl().toString(), cellAddr.reference));              
                  batchEntry.changeInputValueLocal(updateReference);
                  BatchUtils.setBatchId(batchEntry, cellAddr.reference);
                  BatchUtils.setBatchOperationType(batchEntry, BatchOperationType.UPDATE);

                  // add the copy to the batch list
                  batchRequest.getEntries().add(batchEntry);
              }


              // Submit the update
              Link batchLink = cellFeed.getLink(Link.Rel.FEED_BATCH, Link.Type.ATOM);
              service.setHeader("If-Match", "*");
              CellFeed batchResponse = service.batch(new URL(batchLink.getHref()), batchRequest);
              service.setHeader("If-Match", null);
```

Modified version of https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#updating_multiple_cells_with_a_batch_request

Issue: Does not check for strings in the formulas

AppCell contains: row, col & reference